# PIL open.image & convert problems

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

The PIL Image.open.convert(L) give me a strange result :

```
   from PIL import Image

   test_img = Image.open('test.jpg').convert('L')

   imshow(test_img)

   show()
```

1. it rotate the image (?)
2. it doesn't convert it in L (?)

(sorry, I'm new so I cannot send images as demonstration)

Why (if you have an idea)?

Comment: I don't see any reason why your code should rotate the image. Conversion affects the pixel values however it doesn't transform the image. This happens with every image you tested ?

Comment: It's possible that the image you're trying to rotate has a strange bit of EXIF data: https://github.com/kylefox/python-image-orientation-patch

Comment: @user1573642 If you cant send images as demonstration then provide link to image that demonstrate your problem. This way other users with more reputation will probably edit your question and put that image in question for you :) Feel free to inform me about image you wish to put in question and I will try to help.

Answer (score 3):

Your image is rotated because of an origin inconsistency bewteen `Image` and  `pylab`.
If you use this snippet, the image will not be rotated upside-down.

```
import pylab as pl
import Image

im = Image.open('test.jpg').convert('L')
pl.imshow(im, origin='lower')
pl.show()
```

However, the image will not be displayed in black and white. To do so, you need to specify a greyscale colormap:

```
import pylab as pl
import Image
import matplotlib.cm as cm

im = Image.open('test.jpg').convert('L')
pl.imshow(im, origin='lower', cmap=cm.Greys_r)
pl.show()
```

*Et voilà!*

Answer (score 2):

The rotation is because the PIL and matplotlib don't use the same conventions. If you do an test_img.show() it will not rotate the image.
Alternatively you can convert your image to a numpy array before display with matplotlib:

```
imshow(np.asarray(test_img))
```

As for the .convert('L') method, it works for me :

```
test_img = Image.open('test.jpg').convert('L')
print test_img.mode
# 'L'
```